# A word for "rate of change"

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, single-word-requests, synonyms

Physics problems are usually written like:

> The rate of change of the soup's temperature ...

Is there a **common** English word that captures "rate of change" or "speed of change" in a single word, other than *derivative*?

Comment: That's hard, because phrases like "rate of change" have such specific technical meanings that something will invariably be lost in their substitution. Another example is "goodness of fit". I would argue that "derivative" is actually not a good synonym for "rate of change" because it denotes the mathematical operation associated with a "rate of change", but not the notion of "rate of change" itself.

Comment: Are you looking for a word that is valid in a specific context, or in general?

Comment: However, if you are looking for synonyms for the mathematical idea of a derivative, there are: 1) differential coefficient; 2) gradient/slope function; or simply, 3) differential.

Comment: @Gilead - I provided _gradient_ below.  _Slope_ is also a synonym for "rate of change" but I couldn't imagine using the word _slope_ in the context of soup:-)

Comment: "Speed" is rate of change of position.  "Acceleration" is rate of change of speed.  "Jerk" is rate of change of acceleration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Speed is used for the rate of change of distance with respect to time.  Sometimes speed is used in contexts similar to what you mention.

> How quickly will the soup reach room temperature.

Comment: I'm settling for "growth speed", "motion speed", and "temperature speed".  Its a bit awkward, but I like how speed is scalar and doesn't imply direction, leaving the quantity that is changing to determine direction (negative growth=shrinkage, negative motion=backwards, negative temp=cooling)

Comment: Sorry, that should have been _heat speed_, not temperature speed, since temperature is not a verb

Comment: @bobobobo - _heat speed_ doesn't really work, even in your example sentence, "the heat speed of the soup..." would be quite wrong.  How are you planning to use the term?  I should add that @David's rephrasing is just fine if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @bobobobo "growth rate" -> growth rate, "motion speed" -> speed, and "temperature speed" -> warming rate. This is because growth already implies delta size vs. delta time; warming implies delta Temp vs. delta time.

Comment: I am purposefully using the same word to mean "rate of change" - even if it does not quite seem to fit at first.  Can you point out what is wrong with __heat speed__, except that it is not in common use (yet? ;)  I'm talking about the _rate of change of the temperature of the soup_ - in other words, the __heating speed__ of the soup.  If it is +, then the soup is heating, if it is -, the soup is cooling.

Answer (score 5):

I tend to use 'delta', but it's what I call an 'acquired' definition - it's one I picked up along the way, but I have no idea if it's the correct one.

Comment: Differential or delta is what I would use, but only with scientists and mathematicians.  Otherwise I would always say "rate of change".

Comment: Delta technically denotes "change" though, not "rate of change". In a difference quotient, the ratio of two deltas give a rate of change.

Comment: I think saying "delta f" or "the delta of f" or "the difference of f" is fine if f is sampled. The denominator in the quotient is the trivial "1 sample", and it's easily inferred. That said, it's the equivalent of "the derivative of f with respect to" in the continuous case, so I think, as per the question's exclusion of "derivative", it's not really the answer. All I could think of was Newton's "fluxion", and that fails for being uncommon.

Comment:  *soup* / *t* (I came here to mention fluxions.)

Answer (score 3):

Another synonym is "velocity".  In pediatrics they say "height velocity" to refer to the growth in stature per year.  For the second derivative you can say "acceleration".

Comment: Good answer.  Going with [speed](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12509/a-word-for-rate-of-change/12521#12521), it should not imply a direction

Answer (score 2):

You could use *gradient* for the example given, e.g. "the soup was being warmed with a temperature *gradient* of 10 degrees every 5 minutes".

Comment: That's not a typical use of gradient - usually it means the differential in physical space...

Comment: @HorusKol: There you go. Differential is the right word.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Consider the OP's sample sentence. If you had substituted "differential" into it, it would read: "The differential of the soup's temperature...", a substitution which does not seem to be correct in the given context.

Comment: Differential doesn't imply the rate of change with respect to time the same way that speed does.

Comment: @HorusKol - I agree.  The only phrase I personally would ever use is "rate of change".

Comment: @Yitzchak - did you mean to comment rather than answer? _Differential_ does not mean rate of change.

Comment: The NOAD reports that the meaning of _gradient_ is _an increase or decrease in the magnitude of a property (e.g., temperature, pressure, or concentration) observed in passing from one point or moment to another_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - exactly, when you look at the _gradient_ or _slope_ of how a variable changes over time you are measuring the increase or decrease of the variable as you pass from one point or moment to another.  _Temperature gradient_ is perfectly correct.

Comment: @ukayer: I was referring to the first comment of HorusKol. Clearly in physics, _gradient_ refers to the change between different points in the space; as modern physics introduced the concept of four-dimensional space, even a change between two different moments is a change that happens in two different points of the four-dimensional space. I am sorry for the confusion: I should have said to whom was directed the comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, the 'differential of a temperature measurement' would actually refer to the change in temperature, and not the rate of change.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I see where you're coming from, but in a physical/mathematical sense gradient does not imply a rate of change, except when talking about a graph of the measured value. Although, I accept that it is sometimes used as such.

Comment: @HorusKol: The question asks for a _common English word_; what I reported in my other comment is the meaning of the word reported by the NOAD, which (right after the sentence I quoted) reports also _the rate of such a change_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno You're technically correct but if someone started off with "the gradient of the soup's temperature" my first thought would be a temperature gradient in the volume of the soup. At least for me the default units are spatial.

Comment: @eryksun - _gradient_ doesn't have any default units.  I think you might be thinking of hill-climbing.  A hill has a _gradient_ which is the rate of change of height over distance.  A _temperature gradient_ could be the rate of change of temperature over time (as in the soup example) or over distance, e.g. the _temperature gradient_ in a room might be the rate of change of temperature over distance from the radiator/heater.

Comment: @ukayer I didn't mean any technically defined 'default units' -- just my immediate mental conception when hearing "the gradient of the soup's temperature". I realize it can be generalized to any units and number of dimensions. As to the technical definition, the gradient is the vector field of partial derivatives of a scalar field that points in the direction of max slope with a magnitude equal to the max rate of change. The directional derivative is the dot product of the gradient and a unit vector.

Comment: As a base case, y = f(x) has a gradient of ∂f/∂x*i, where i is the unit vector in the +x direction. If the partial derivative is negative, it means the steepest ascent is in the -i direction. Also, there are only 2 possible unit vectors, i and -i. In the i direction, the slope is dot(∂f/∂x*i, i) = ∂f/∂x, and in the -i direction, the slope is dot(∂f/∂x*i, -i) = -∂f/∂x. In a function from R1->R1, using a gradient is pretty silly. Typically it's for R3 -> R1 scalar fields (such as temperature in space). In the more general case of mapping Rn -> Rm, the m x n Jacobian matrix of gradients is used.

Comment: Yeah I meant to comment. 
@Gilead: Consider this structure of the sample sentence: "The soup's temperature differential..."

Comment: @Yitzchak, it still doesn't sound unambiguous to me, because in this context, differential could mean "change" ($\delta T$) rather than rate of change (dT/dt).

Answer (score 0):

If you were an economist you might talk about the "marginal increase in temperature of the soup". Outside economics the word is not used very much in that sense.